# Decreasing nav mesh boundary size

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, navmesh

So I have this setup:

[image]

As you can see there is enough room for the actor to go through the gap between the cubes, but the navmesh is not present there.
Is there a way to make the navmesh to be generated a little closer to the objects so my actor can fit though this gap?

For reference the gap has 100 units of size. Navmesh actor width is set to 34

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust navigation mesh parameters from Project Settings -> Navigation Mesh -> Generation.
To achieve what you are asking you can regulate

- `Agent Radius`: the radius of the smallest agent to traverse the navmesh;
- `Cell Size`: dimension of the cells the build up the navigation mesh (the small is the size the more precise the navigation will be but it makes the navigation heavier to calculate.

Here you can see what I'm talking about:

[image: reference]